# Access JSON Array with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I get an JSON array via an Ajax request. This one looks like this:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "title":"Frau",
      "academic_title":null,
      "first_name":"Lynda",
      "last_name":"McCrow",
      "company":"Tekfly",
      "street":"Sage",
      "zip":"4860-077",
      "country":"Portugal",
      "city":"Quinta",
      "phone":"6727086107",
      "fax":"4941912651",
      "mobile":"3722716317",
      "email":"lmccrow7@newyorker.com",
      "web":"shop-pro.jp",
      "mailbox":"81-0982335",
      "mailbox_country":"Indonesia",
      "mailbox_zip":null,
      "mailbox_city":"Susoh",
      "birthday":"1977-02-11"
   }
}
```

But I have no idea, how to access the JSON array. I already tried all of this:

```
success: function(data) {
 console.log(data[0].data.title);
 console.log(data[0].title);
 console.log(data.data[0].title);
 console.log(data.title);
}
```

Can you guys give me a hint?

Kind regards

Comment: this is an object not an array.Try data.data.title

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have tried everything except:

```
data.data.title
```

It's an Object and you need to use `Object.key()` or something to iterate. Technically, it's like this:

```js
// Inside your function, this is what gets passed.
data = {  
   "data":{  
      "title":"Frau",
      "academic_title":null,
      "first_name":"Lynda",
      "last_name":"McCrow",
      "company":"Tekfly",
      "street":"Sage",
      "zip":"4860-077",
      "country":"Portugal",
      "city":"Quinta",
      "phone":"6727086107",
      "fax":"4941912651",
      "mobile":"3722716317",
      "email":"lmccrow7@newyorker.com",
      "web":"shop-pro.jp",
      "mailbox":"81-0982335",
      "mailbox_country":"Indonesia",
      "mailbox_zip":null,
      "mailbox_city":"Susoh",
      "birthday":"1977-02-11"
   }
};

for (var key in data.data) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${data.data[key]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`data` is not an array, nor JSON, it's an object literal. Your last try comes close, but you need to access

```
data.data.title
```

or you could destructure `data` in the success param

```
success: function({data}) {
    // now you could access data.title directly
    console.log(data.title);
}
```